# Cassandra Timeout Issues Raspberry Pi

Tags: cassandra, timeout, raspberry-pi3, cqlsh

I have been working to setup a cassandra instance on a raspberry pi. Whenever I start this instance I get the error message:

`('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': OperationTimedOut('errors=Timed out creating connection (5 seconds), last_host=None',))}`

I've tried to change the timeout time for cqlsh in the cqlsh script file, changed anything that said timeout in the cassandra.yaml file, and tried to add a cqlshrc file in my ~/.cassandra file but none of it worked.

I am running a Raspberry Pi 3 and my CPU is running at like

`load average: 130.15 128.67 112.31`

So I am wondering if this is a hardware issue causing this timeout.
Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Anything Java related will be tight on an RPi. What are you giving the Java process resource-wise?

Comment: Cassandra seems to be eating most of the memory and CPU

400% CPU, 61% Memory

Comment: Cassandra relies on ram and fast io (and CPU during compaction). Java alone is a little problematic because of resource constraints, I think Cassandra might be asking too much. You might be able to tune the JVM to help a little, but io will always be an issue. If you're looking to try out distributed DBs on there RPi is probably choose a different one. Good luck!

Comment: Add more pis or tune your configs. 130 load is 25 times what you want it to be, its overloaded.